# Unable to increment a global variable

Tags: php

I need a variable to be passed along several functions & if statements, i'm going to keep it short.
I start off with initializing a static counter which i will use to keep track of the case number in my mysql database;

```
static $counter = 1;
```

then i write my function in which i try to simply increment my global variable (this is in an if statement inside my function);

```
$counter++;
```

Now my code compiles and runs perfectly but the counter seems to never increment and give every case id 1.
Anyone know how i managed to mess this up?

EDIT (Current structure):

```
<?php
static $counter = 1;
function frontend($connection){
   global $counter;
   (...)
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       (...)
       if(isset($_POST['betaald'])){
           $counter++;
       }
    }
} ...
```

Now this code makes a neat database of all i need except the counter which seems to be unchangeable.

Comment: Have you used the [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword as the first line in your function?

Comment: `static` !== `global`

Comment: can you updated code related static and increment

Comment: I've looked into the global variables as i figured that might give a problem now as far as i understand the global should be called in the function after which you can edit the value, thus in my function i added        global $counter; which did not help.

Comment: DarkBee that makes sense but it gives me a Fatal error; Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active in ...

Answer (score 0):

Explain more about your code and see the example.

```
    <?php
   function keep_track() {
      STATIC $count = 0;
      $count++;
      print $count;
      print "<br />";
   }

   keep_track();
   keep_track();
   keep_track();
?>
```

This will produce the following result −

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: What you made function in and of itself is implemented in my function, although perhaps you are right in the sense that it might be easier to create a new function for that all toghether. Will update my question to show the structure in my program as of now.